# Cannot install Windows 2012 R2 on HP Blades

Tags: windows, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, blade-server

I have several HP ProLiant BL460c G1 blade servers where I am trying to install Windows 2012 R2.  I was able to get it installed on one but can't get it installed on the rest.  They all fail with the following error:

"Setup cannot continue due to a corrupted installation file.  Contact the vendor of your Windows installation disc or your system administrator for assistance."

The media works as I've used it on other systems.  I have tried updating the firmware, using iLo and DVD mounting for the ISO, etc. but no luck.  Same problem on 5+ blades yet one somehow got it installed.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I know that these are older blades and they may not be officially supported on 2012 R2, but I need to get these servers up for testing purposes.

Comment: It sounds like it isn't playing nice with the storage controller/driver.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Any suggestions on how I might be able to update the storage controller/driver?

Comment: If there isn't a specific driver for the controller on HPs site for 2012, figure out which model the controller is, and see if the manufacturer has one. Or install 2008 R2 and do an in-place upgrade.

Comment: I had to do an in-place upgrade as @DanBig suggested on some older SuperMicro hardware for this same reason/same error. It was definitely a storage controller driver issue. The in-place upgrade was the only way I could seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a full firmware upgraded using Smart Update Firmware DVD. You could also try to install 2012 via the smartstart CD but might fail as it might not support 2012.

You can try this link http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?lang=en&cc=us&sp4ts.oid=3288156 to get all your CD's and drivers/PSP for 2008 then the in-place upgrade might work that was already recommended.

The main problem is this first gen server dosen't have 2012 on it's support list so it's going to be hard to get 2012 working correctly on it.

Answer (score 0):

On older hardware, If there isn't a specific driver for the controller on the system manufacturers (in this case, HP) site for 2012, figure out which model the controller is, and see if the controller manufacturer has one.

Or install 2008 R2 and do an in-place upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried installing 2008 R2 which seemed to complete but every time the blades boot they hang on the Windows starting logo.  Weird.  2008 R2 should definitely be supported.